# How to loop through allocated memory with pointer arithmetic C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

In order to loop through a regular int array with pointer arithmetic looks like such:

```
 int *p;
 int arraySize = 20;

 int array[arraySize];     

 for (p = array; p< array+(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); p++){
    int random = rand() % 200;
    *p = random;
  }

 for (p = array; p< array+(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); p++){
    printf("%d\t%x\n", *p, p);
  }



 for (p = array; p<array+(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); p++){
        int random = rand() % 200;
        *p = random;
  }

 for (p = array; p< array+(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); p++){
        printf("%d\t%x\n", *p, p);
  }
```

However, I want to declare:

```
int *array = (int*) calloc(arraySize, sizeof(int));
```

I am very confused on how to loop through dynamically allocated memory as opposed to a regular static array.

Comment: Replace *every* `(sizeof(array)/sizeof(int))` with `arraySize` and both should function as you desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *array = (int*)calloc(arraySize, sizeof(int));
int *array_end = array + arraySize;
int* ptr;
for(ptr = array; ptr < array_end; ptr++)
    printf("%p\t%d", ptr, *ptr);
```

Comment: code only answers are not all that useful. Please try to add some explaination.